# $\pi = 4 \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^{2}} dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was looking into mathematical magazine and I find out some interesting integral but I could not know how they come up with that:
Recall $$(2k-1)!!=(2k-1)(2k-3)...5.3.1$$

$\begin{align}
\pi &= 4 \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^{2}} dx \\
&= 4 \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+x} \sqrt{1-x} dx \\
&= 4 \left[ \frac{-2}{3} \sqrt{1+x} (\sqrt{1-x})^{3} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{k} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k-3)!!}{2^{k} (\sqrt{1+x})^{2k-1}}. \frac{(-1)^{k+1} 2^{k+1} (\sqrt{1-x})^{2k+3}}{(2k+3)!!}  \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= 4 \left[ \frac{-2}{3} \sqrt{1+x} (\sqrt{1-x})^{3} + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k}(\sqrt{1-x})^{2k+3}}{(2k+3)(2k+1)(2k-1)(\sqrt{1+x})^{2k-1}} \right]_{0}^{1}
\end{align} 
$
Mainly I do not know what happen from step 2 to 3. Any hints or explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: Please could you provide more context to why they want to do this? e.g. this is simple to evaluate via a simple "$u= \sin x $" substitution .

Comment: Yes, I understand. He is just trying to involve integration by parts with infinite series . The only thing was written before starting this idea is : There are several ways to find i.p series for $\pi$. The first we present uses the fact that $\pi$ is the area of the unit circle. Recall ......

Comment: Might help to provide the link....

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Kilmer2-0801921.pdf

Comment: Integration by parts and taylor expansion.